# How to include JSP file in JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a problem to include JSP file into JSP. It worked before I deploy. When I deploy web project, exception occurred:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: File [/spring-boot-web-jsp-1.0/resources/static/lib_head.jsp] not found
```

But when I browse to check path of this file it worked. So what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the leading `/` from the path - `spring-boot-web-jsp-1.0/resources/static/lib_head.jsp`

Servlets tend to break when the path is relative.

Another note, I'm not sure how it is in JSP but in spring boot usually you don't need the full path because the folder `static` (`src/main/resources/static`) is exposed by default so it should be just `lib_head.jsp` unless the defaults are overridden or it works differently when including JSP.